# Adding Web Refrence to Visual Studio while Connected to VPN

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, proxy, vpn

i am connected to my clients network using vpn.

I need to use a exposed webservice of the Project server in their network.

when i tried the url http://server:port/service.asmx?wsdl in browser i get the wsdl.

But when i try to add web refrence in visual studio i says There is a error downloading the  http://server:port/service.asmx?wsdl.could not resolve proxy.MycompanyDomain.com.

Why it is not by passing my company's domain. How to resolve it.

Comment: In addition to being connected to VPN, do you have any proxy settings configured in your browser?

Comment: I have done the proxy settings for firefox but can not access the proxy settings of IE, as they are disabled by admin

Comment: Add the proxy settings to your devenv.exe.config file.  Directions are [here](http://gurustop.net/blog/2010/08/10/visual-studio-2010-extension-manager-online-gallery-behind-internet-proxy/)

Answer (score 0):

You could create a concrete WSDL by downloading the file from your browser and crating your web reference against the WSDL file rather than against the URL. This can be useful when you want to be sure you have a copy of the service interface at a point in time (particularly if the service is third party and may have unexpected changes that you want to flag back to them).